# How to get Ropsten Revival testnet eth without mining

Tags: testnets, ropsten

I've synchronized my testnet node to Ropsten Revival tesntet as shown here: https://github.com/ethereum/ropsten

However, I have no testnet eth to play with it. I tried mining, but no lack. Is there any faucet or something that can be used to obtained Ropsten Revival testnet ether?

Thank you.